# AWS API Intergration with Mulesoft

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, mulesoft

I am trying to call my AWS API through mulesoft.

My AWS API is perfectly working in browser and Postman.
I have created HTTP listener and HTTP request in mulesoft but it is giving HTTP connectivity error.

Does anyone have any reference material to connect AWS API through mulesoft?

Comment: You should provide more details. Are you trying exactly the same request? Did you enable HTTP wire logging in Mule to see if there is an HTTP error? What connectivity error exactly? Are you doing the postman and mule test from the same computer? Is it using the same authentication?
There is nothing specific in Mule to connect to AWS. It is just an HTTP request. It should match exactly what it is working in the Postman request.

Comment: It's true, we can't know the reason from just what you've said here, but I will tell you that the most common reason for something to work from browser and test client, but not with the Mule app is when a browser is configured with proxy or firewall, and the app needs to be configured for the same thing. Otherwise it's a misconfiguration of the HTTP request connector.